# iOS6- UITable View Controller Table Under Navigation Bar like iOS7

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, ios6, uitableview

I am currently making an app and am trying to get it to support both iOS6 and iOS7. My main view is a UITableViewController. When I scroll down, I hide the navigation bar. In iOS7 views start underneath navigation bars by default so hiding the navigation bar basically extends the table. But on iOS6 the table view starts below the navigation bar, so when it is hidden there is a white space where it used to be.

How can I make it so on ios6 the table also starts underneath the navigation bar?

I know that it would probably be easier to do this if my view was not a UITableView, but I already set it up that way and am also using its UIRefreshControl functionality.

Comment: I think you should have to display under the navigation bar, that is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Make your navigation bar translucent and this way you will be able to extend table view all the way up underneath navigation bar.

Comment: If cake man is still here he should accept this, neatest solution imo.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6, try to call `setFrame` using UIView animation and adjust the `frame (y and height for this case)` of your UITableViewController's view as per the need.

Answer (score 0):

Give the tableView the full height (y=0, height = 548) and set its contentInset to 44 pixels, or the height of the navigation bar.